# Is a Constructor a Routine?

Tags: oop

Currently we are writing our bachelor thesis about the implementation of a Compiler for an academic object-oriented mini programming language.

We want to be precise in our documentation, and we're currently discussing if a constructor is a routine.

What we think points out that a constructor **is** a routine is that it has a block of Commands, Parameters and local variables. Despite the missing name, all other attributes of other routines are given.

What we think points out that a constructor **is not** a routine is that it can only be called once per instance.

We are not sure if this question has a clear answer, or if the definition is different from theory to theory.

We would be happy if someone could give a pointer to some literature about this semantic question.

Best

Edit: Some Information about how we name specific things in our Language:

- We have functions and procedures. Functions do have a return value, procedures don't.
- A constructor is like an unnamed procedure (without explicit return value)
- a constructor is called implicit, java like: `x := new X(1, new Y())`
- Parameters are defined during the definition of a constructor. The own instance (`this`) is not considered a parameter but provided implicitly

Thanks for your answers so far, they're helping with the though process.

Comment: There's lots of room for interpretation: I say a constructor has a name, but no return type. The name of the constructor needs to be the same as the class name :-)

Comment: Well, in our language it does not have a name but an own keyword (constr, we weren't creative here). It does not have a return type.

Comment: If this question is "unclear" then which question is not unclear?

Comment: A constructor is a routine in your language if you define it as such. It all depends on what you put in your specification.

Comment: This might be a better question for [programmers.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on language - and for this academic language - I would *not say* that a constructor is a routine. I say that because in *not saying* that it is a routine, a separation is kept: *unless the language explicitly unifies routines/functions/constructors, don't say it does :)*

Now, consider these counter-examples (and there are many more, I am sure):

- Languages like Eiffel allow giving constructors different names (which I think is awesome and wish was used more).
- Languages like Ruby don't have a "new" operator and invoking a constructor appears as invoking any (class) method. Ruby doesn't even have a way of signaling that a method acts as a constructor (or factory method, as it were).
- Constructors in languages like JavaScript are just functions which can be *run* in a special context when used with `new`.

Also, at some level it may be viewed that there needs to be no difference in calling a constructor multiple times (you get back a new object - so what?) than calling a function multiple times (where one might get back the same value). Consider that the new object may be immutable and may have value equality with other objects.

That is, considering the following code, is there a constructor used?

```
5 4 vec2 "1" int 2 vec2 add puts
```

I made it up, but I hope it makes a point. There may or may not be a constructor or an external difference between a constructor and an ordinary function depending upon how *the specific language* views the role (or even need) of constructors.

Now, write the language specification as deemed fit and try to *avoid leaking implementation details*.

Comment: Yeah, I think if we're going to decide the naming convention in the doc ourselfes it's very important to make it as clear as possible. We're going to write a language design document (with the thoughs behind the design), and afterwards a language specification (which HAS implementation specifics, since we're going to mix the grammar, context restrictions and code generation.

Comment: @Christof Start with the least promises and most conceptual distinction (giving each term a separate meaning) and continuously refine it as the language develops. It's often easier to generalize two concepts (if they end up being suitably generalizable) than to try and unravel two different concepts sharing the same name.

Comment: As for the Ruby, there's `XClass.new` and `initialize()` pair that have idiomatic "createit" and "initializeme" meanings, automatically available for any class unless you somehow override them. That's perfectly like a new operator and a constructor, just heavily customizable ;)

Answer (score 2):

Constructor is a constructor.

It may be like a function(that returns value: the new object), procedure(routine, function with no return value, called on uninitialized object), it may be callable once or many times on an object (although it is arguable whever the object is of the same identity afterwards..),  it may have a name or not or the name may be enforced to match the class, etc. The constructor may even "not exist" or be implicitly created by the compiler from various scattered initializers and code blocks, which otherwise would be expressions/routines/whatchamacallit.

It all depends on your language that you compile and on what do you mean by 'function', 'routine', or even 'parameters' (i.e. is 'this' a parameter?).

If you want to ask about such thing, first describe/define your language and all your terms that you want to use (what is a class? method? function? routine? parameter? constructor? ...) and then, well, most probably you will automatically deduce the answer matching your ontology.

Comment: Well, I'd say that `this` is a parameter, because otherwise how does a constructor know to which instance it is applied?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can find some updated information in the edit of the question, but I think what you really want to tell us is that we have to decide on our own.

Comment: @Christof: well.. yes. You got me perfectly right. I understand that you want to be correct in your work, but facing real world, people and linguistics/formalisms, it depends heavily on who do you work with and who will be checking it. You are working in some environment and you might need to stick to their terminology or define your own. Whatever reasonable or not response you find here, be sure to doublecheck at your local professors..

Comment: old enough to have many well-reviewed resources, where you will find good terms to use/refer/link/quote/etc. 'Internet' is weak medium for publications. It's hardly acceptable to quote 'StackOverflow, question 213123' as a reference in the bibliography;)

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is a function with special semantics (such that it is called in specific context - as part of object construction), but it is a function anyway - it can have parameters, it has usual flow of control, it can have local variables, etc. It is not better or worse than any other function. I'd say it is a routine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a `Routine` is what is that can be called *explicitly* as and when required by the caller on a constructed object/class, while a `constructor` can be called a special type of routine that is called at runtime when the instance of the class is *requested*.

- A constructor helps only in constructing and initializing the class
  object and its variables.
- It *may or may not* accept parameters, it can be overloaded with
  different set of parameters
- If the constructor has no parameters and also no code inside its code
  block, you may want to omit it
- Some languages automatically create a default parameter-less
  constructor (like C#) if you do not provide your own constructor
- A constructor *can* have an access modifier to restrict the creation
  scope of the class
- A constructor cannot have a return type because its constructing the
  same class in which it is declared, and obviously there is no point
  returning the same type (may be that's the reason some languages use same name for the constructor as the class name)
- All the implementation rules for a constructor *differ* from language to language
- Furthermore, the **most important** requirement of a well written constructor is that after it is executed it should leave the class object in a valid state

Comment: Okay, suppose you have a binary operator `+` overloaded in C++ and implemented as a free-standing function. Is calling this function *required* by the caller when the user just happens to write `A+B` and `A` and `B` happen to have types that match the function signature?

Comment: Those statements are not all true, here are just a few rebuttals: Constructors can indeed have different return types. A constructor does not need to support access modifies. A constructor (or language) need not support overloading.

Comment: A constructor is not called by the compiler but at runtime. Most of the attributes you've written are correct for our language, especially the valid state one (we have no null-references in our language, every constructor for a class has to initialize all fields)

Comment: @Christoff: "valid state" is itself ambiguous term. What does that mean? If I have an 'HeightOfAPerson' class then if the constructor autoinitializes that object with value of ZERO (int's/double's traditional default), does that leave the object in a "valid state"? I know you have meant the 'state' in the lower-level meaning, I try to point out the possible misunderstanding. Constructor does not have to initialize all the fields. I.e. see 2-phase construction. The constructor must set up all the **internal and invisible things** like vtables or GC status flags..

Comment: @Christof, VS1: the "**most important**" thing you included is very very wrong in many languages. If constructor accepts some parameters, how would that constructor **abort and notify about failure** when the parameters are plainly wrong? In many languages, the constructor is strictly required to **throw**, because there is no way of 'returning error code' or even 'returning null' instead of an apparently-ready-to-use-object-instance! Maybe you have meant something else? Please review the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks @Quetzalcoatl I updated my last sentence, I completely forgot about invalid parameters which if sent, the constructor should throw exception..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl, you are right that this isn't valid for all programming languages (for example in Java you can still have uninitialized fields after the constructor), but in our special case it's necessary to initialize every field of the class. I would argue that in Java it's a valid state for an instance to have uninitialized fields. Of course this is about the technical state, not about checking the values itself. We won't allow a constructor to fail, and we don't implement runtime exceptions (with the exception of divided by zero which leads to program abortion)

Comment: @Christof: (1) with parametric ctors, no error reporting from ctors leads to constant usage of 2-phase construction where in the 2nd phase you'll be able to report error. IMHO, if ctor is not allowe to fail, then you may start removing the parametric constructors from the lang spec. (2) there are 'exceptions' and 'exceptions'. By 'runtime exceptions' you might mean the hardwarelevel ones, or just error messages thrown by the user code which also are called 'runtime' because they happen at runtime or because a person worked in Java where there was the evil-or-holy RuntimeException class..

Comment: I hope you have your spec well thought and that you'll be careful with definitions. I'm "walking off", as I/We are starting to detoriate from the main question furhter and further. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The Implementation of the code generation is already finished, and example programs (like a linked list) compile and run fine. We are currently revisiting and rephrasing the design desicions we made a long time ago for the documentation, and on the last parts of context restrictions. Since until now everything is working fine, and measuring from the many thoughts we put into the specification I think the spec should be at least OK.

Answer (score 1):

From outside, a constructor can be seen as a class method, with an instance of that class as return value. Insofar, the claim that "it can only be used once per instance" does not hold water, since there is no instance yet when the constructor is used.

From inside, some special keywordish name like "this" is bound to the uninitialized instance.

Usually, there is some syntactic sugar, like a new keyword. Also, the compiler may help to make sure the instance is properly initialized.

It is special insofar as the functionality of creating a new object is nowhere else provided. But as far as its usage is concerned, a constructor is not (or at least should not be) different from any other class method that happens to return an instance of the class.

BTW, is "routine" an established term in OOP?

Comment: On `routine`: I think OOP defines only "methods". I actually doubt the abstract OOP dwelves into a 'constructor' thing at all. I think it just operates on create, destroy, and sendmessage (a.k.a call, invoke) terms.

Answer (score -1):

A constructor (as in the name) is only executed by the compiler when you create a new instance of that class.

The general idea is this: You put some set of operations which should be executed during the startup and that is what is done on the constructor. So this implies, you cannot call a constructor just like the other methods of your class.

Comment: Huh? A Constructor is not executed by the compiler but on runtime when a new instance of an object is created.

`x = new X()` is an example for calling a constructor during the runtime of a program.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.. A constructor is only executed when an object is created or in other words, an instance of that class is executed..

Comment: Actually, you are creating an object(this means, constructor is executed automatically). You are not actually calling it like the other methods in your class. Suppose you have a testmethod in X, you do objectofX.testmethod() but in similar, you cannot do with a constructor such as objectofX.X() is not valid..

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean whit that it's not possible to call the constructor more than one time. Our compile target is the JVM, so we are first creating a new Instance of the Object (reserving memory), and afterward calling the constructor on VM level. On Programming language level, this two steps are compressed into one.

Comment: @Christof: ok. So, why the downvote? I still can't figure out what's wrong in my answer

Comment: A downvote might have came from anyone. Not only the author of the question (Christof) can downvote. Almost any user of SO can downvote. Someone disagreed with your description and downvoted. Pity that he did not left a comment. Probably he will never rewisit. Just happens.